# Sorting based on max length and max sum

Tags: python, list, sorting

Can you please help me figure this out

```
q = [[12, 13, 14], [8, 9, 10,11], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

suppose I've a list like q, How do I sort the based on

1. Max length of sublists and
2. Max sum of the sublists

The output should be:

```
q = [[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14][5,6,7],[1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supply your criteria in a lambda function for the `key`:

```
sorted(q, key=lambda sub: (len(sub), sum(sub)), reverse=True)
>>> [[8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4]]
```

The `lambda` function will take every sub-list `x` and sort it based on it's `len`, in cases where the result of `len` is not sufficient in making a decision, the `sum` of their contents is used to break the tie.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sorted(q, lambda a,b: len(b)-len(a) or sum(b)-sum(a))
```

Comment: Ahhh it is using `cmp` in Python 2. I had completely forgotten that, I would urge you to point that out, this is not the most portable option ;-).